# Lumen 5.3 Undefined variable: closure

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

From composer I Created a project from laravel/lumen. I un-commented the route middleware

```
$app->routeMiddleware([
    'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
]);`
```

and my routes added the auth middleware.

```
$app->get('/', ['middleware'=>'auth'], function () use ($app) {
    return $app->version();
});
```

I get `ErrorException in RoutesRequests.php line 656: Undefined variable: closure`

I googled this and it seams to be a problem in 5.2 but I have 5.3 downloaded. Without the middleware I Get `Lumen (5.3.3) (Laravel Components 5.3.*)`

Comment: App\Http\Middleware\AuthenticationMiddleware::class

Comment: The class is called Authenticate not AuthenticationMiddleware.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The closure should be the last item in your array.  Change your route to:

```
$app->get('/', ['middleware'=>'auth', function () use ($app) {
    return $app->version();
}]);
```